# Copy offset range

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA macro to copy paste cells. The problem is that I have to copy this macro like 30 times and go through each case. I have same amount of rows in between, only starting row is changing. I would like to modify my macro to "copy offset" from the first row. So in this particular case anchor cell is D13.

I have tried to use `copySheet.Offset(17, 1).Copy` ("D14:E30") but this does not seems to work?

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Calculation")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Calculation")

Range("D13").MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

copySheet.Range("D14:E30").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Range("D31").MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(18, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

copySheet.Range("D32:E33").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(19, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Range("D163").MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(150, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

copySheet.Range("D164:E167").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(151, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get from `Range("D13")` to `Range("D14:E30")` you can use a combination of the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Offset) and the [Range.Resize property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Resize).

```
Dim StartRange As Range
Set StartRange = copySheet.Range("D13")

'D14:E30
StartRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(17, 2).Copy

'D32:E33
StartRange.Offset(19, 0).Resize(2, 2).Copy
```

You can adapt that to your other copy statements. So if you change your `StartRange` all the others change accordingly.

Comment: That works! Can it be used for merged cells like `Range("D13").MergeArea.Copy`? These are D13:E13 and are merged. I have tried `StartRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 0).MergeArea.Copy`

Comment: @user7202022 and what happend? What about `StartRange.MergeArea.Copy` instead?

Comment: This works for D13. How about `Range("D31").MergeArea.Copy`? Should I Dim a new one for D31?

Comment: @user7202022 just offset from your start range D13 `StartRange.Offset(18, 0).MergeArea.Copy`

Comment: Perfect! Huge thanks goes to Mr. PeH! Now I get it how it works!

Answer (score 1):

`copySheet.Offset(1, 1).Copy` does not work, because `.Offset()` needs Cell or Range reference.

E.g. `copySheet.Range("A10").Offset(1, 1).Copy`

---

If you want to copy offset from `D13:E40`, then this is a possible option:

`copySheet.Range("D13:E40").Offset(17, 1).Copy`

Comment: Thanks for that `copySheet.Range("A10").Offset(1, 1).Copy` is copying 1 cell that is located one down and one to the left. So it is basically A11. How I can copy range that is starting from A11 and is generally (A11:B12) without inputting exact range but using Offset?