# How to Dim cells(xx, columns.count)

Tags: excel, vba

This question is follow-up to already answered question ([Copy offset range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764172)). How to `Dim` `Cells(13, Columns.Count)` so there is no need to change "13" all the time in next macros but only once.

Something like this?

```
Dim cello As Cell
Set cello = Cells(13, Columns.Count)
```

Part from original code:

```
StartRange.MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(17, 2).Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(18, 0).MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(18, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(19, 0).Resize(2, 2).Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(19, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(150, 0).MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(150, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(151, 0).Resize(4, 2).Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(151, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

-------------- EDIT -------------------

According to suggested solution:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim StartRange As Range
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim cello As Range

Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Calculation")

Set cello = Cells(13, Columns.Count)

Set StartRange = Worksheets("Calculation").Range("D13")

StartRange.MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(17, 2).Copy
pasteSheet.cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(18, 0).MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(18, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(19, 0).Resize(2, 2).Copy
pasteSheet.cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(19, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(150, 0).MergeArea.Copy
pasteSheet.cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(150, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(151, 0).Resize(4, 2).Copy
pasteSheet.cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(151, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set StartRange = Nothing
Set pasteSheet = Nothing
Set cello = Nothing

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

However running this code gives an error "Method or data member not found"? Pointing to "cello" in `pasteSheet.cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

Comment: `dim cello as range:set cello=cells(35,columns.count)`

Comment: Avoid hard-wired constants like `13`. Assign them to a variable in one place and then use that variable in other places.

Comment: It looks that this should work. Why it says "Method or data member not found"? Pointing to "cello"

Comment: Question is the same. I have just added suggested solution to my code and added it as an EDIT.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the suggestion, the point was to not use `Cell` in your declaration of `cello` but instead to use `Range`. The point wasn't to *replace* `Cells` in you code bye `cello`. There is a method named `Cells`, but not one named `cello`. Declaring a variable `cello` doesn't add any new methods.

Comment: Also, since your code repeatedly uses `pasteSheet.Cells(13, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)`, it would make sense to assign *that* to a range variable.

Comment: Sorry. I have made a mistake. I have used `Dim cello As Range` in my code, just copied wrong one here. By using `Dim cello As Range` I am getting an error.

Comment: Ok, got it working! Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I came up with:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim StartRange As Range
Dim cello As Range

Set cello = Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(13, Columns.Count)

Set StartRange = Worksheets("Calculation").Range("D13")

StartRange.MergeArea.Copy
cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(17, 2).Copy
cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(18, 0).MergeArea.Copy
cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(18, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(19, 0).Resize(2, 2).Copy
cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(19, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(150, 0).MergeArea.Copy
cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(150, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

StartRange.Offset(151, 0).Resize(4, 2).Copy
cello.End(xlToLeft).Offset(151, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Set StartRange = Nothing
Set pasteSheet = Nothing
Set cello = Nothing

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```